# iOS Twitter account access

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, twitter

How do I deal with a user who clicks 'Don't Allow' when first prompted '*Example* Would Like Access to Twitter Accounts' ?

[image: Twitter popup]

Is it only possible to give them a popup explaining that they now have to go into the Settings and allow access to the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]. If this returns NO, direct the user to their account page.

Comment: Hey Paul, are you suggeting directing the user just via a pop up with instructions on how to get to the Settings panel? Or are you aware of  a more system wide method (thinking about internationalising the text).

Comment: A popup is the easiest. I am not aware of way to automatically route the user to settings.